# htaccess only allow specific php query

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site, where I grant access to users through an O2Auth provider, so they never have to query `wp-login.php`. But, when users log out, they need to query for `wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnounce=dead0beef`

I want to protect `wp-login` via .htaccess, `Require valid-user`

So can I add a `Require` directive to also allow `action=logout`?

I tried these without success:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "o2a-login" o2a-user
...
Require env o2a_user
```

```
Require expr "(%{QUERY_STRING} =~ logout)"
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} in { 'action=logout(.*)', 'action=logout', '.*logout.*' }"
Require expr "%{QUERY_STRING} in {'wp-login\.php\?action=logout.*'}"
```

Or as an alternative way - Can I respect  wp-logged-in users at Apache?

Comment: Why specifically did you want to use `Require`? This doesn't necessarily look like the right tool for the job?

Comment: Then tell me a better alternative :) I'm no expert in this field. My only goal is to block scriptkiddies and/or bots

Comment: But for what I have seen is it quite common to restrict access to the login page this way

Comment: Yes, you are right, you could use mod_authz_core in this way to restrict access, although you would need additional directives to restrict these directives to requests for `wp-login.php` (eg. `<Files>`) and not the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

> they need to query for `wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnounce=dead0beef`

If you simply want to allow the `action=logout` URL parameter (at the start of the query string) and block all other requests to `wp-login.php` then you can use the following mod_rewrite directives *before* the WordPress front-controller, near the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ - [F]
```

The above states, for all requests to `/wp-login.php` that do not have `action=logout` at the start of the query string then send a 403 Forbidden.

> Can I respect wp-logged-in users at Apache?

You can't determine whether a user is actually logged in to WP from `.htaccess`. You can check that a cookie is set, but you can't authenticate the value of that cookie (with the WP session) - so anyone could potentially set that cookie.

> I wanted to leave wp-login open for admin login without O2A instead of totally blocking it. But I think I will just add anouther allowed query string to do the job.

You could potentially check for a "private" (known only to you) query string to perhaps *obfuscate* the login.

---

**UPDATE:**

> The "obfuscation" string is what I tried. I can access the login form then but the "wp-login" action redirectis back to the URI without this string. So after pressing login I get redirected to the forbidden site and can't log in

You could perhaps set a cookie when passing your secret key in the URL and use this cookie to actually authorise the request instead (survives redirects)? For example:

```
# Set Cookie if "secret key" successfully passed in the query string
# Remove secret key from query string (via 302 redirect)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)(?:^|&)(secret-name)=(secret-value)(&.*|$)
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ /$0?%1%4 [CO=%2:%3:example.com:0:/:secure:HttpOnly,R,L]

# Incorporate test if "secret key" cookie is present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout(?:&|$)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !\bsecret-name=secret-value\b
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ - [F]
```

The `%N` backreferences in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string and *flags* arguments refer to the captured subpatterns in the preceding *CondPattern*.

The "obfuscation string", ie. `secret-name=secret-value` pair, is used to set the cookie on a redirect. So the cookie can be immediately read (and authorise access) on the redirected request. The redirect also removes this "obfuscation string" from the visible query string.

Note that the *session* cookie is only set on *secure* HTTPS connections and is not available to JavaScript.

Alternatively, it would be more secure/easier to authorise by client IP address, but if you have a dynamic IP that may not be practical. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout(?:&|$)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=203.0.113.111
RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ - [F]
```

`203.0.113.111` is your external IP address. Note that since we're using the `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* this is an exact string match (not a regex), so the dots do not need to be backslash escaped.

Comment: Ok now I got your point. I wanted to leave `wp-login` open for admin login without O2A instead of totally blocking it. But I think I will just add anouther allowed query string to do the job. Thanks!

Comment: The "obfuscation" string is what I tried. I can access the login form then but the "wp-login" action redirectis back to the URI without this string. So after pressing login I get redirected to the forbidden site and can't log in

Comment: You could use the "obfuscation string" in the query string to set a cookie that is then used to authorise the request - at least this will persist through redirects. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't know if that's a very good solution but it works for me:

- First I created a symlink in the wp html root (mostly /var/www/html/) `ln -s wp-login.php mySecretLogin.php`
- Then I added rewrite rules like @MrWhite suggested, to only allow logout AND `mySecretLogin` as referrer
- And prodected `mySecretLogin` by authentication

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mysite\.tld/mySecretLogin(/|\.php)$
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=logout(&|$)
 RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

and

```
<FilesMatch "^mySecretLogin\.php$">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Password please!"
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

This way the `wp-login.php` is only allowed for log-out or via `mysite.tld/mySecretLogin.php` with a password.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution, although I can't see how `mySecretLogin` is set as the HTTP `Referer`? However, you should remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper - if mod_rewrite was somehow disabled on your server then your security would simply be bypassed (rather than generating an error - which would be preferable here).

Comment: It's unlikely to happen that mod_rewrite gets disabled in my server since I'm the only person with filesystem access but I see your point. You never know :)
About the referrer - that's what I see in the logs; and it works. Since that's the file I am accessing, altough it is a symlink.